# Sql ,query for getting total count joining 2 tables

Tags: .net, sql

I am new to sql.

**Here is my question**

The requirement is to join 2 tables and get the total count

`Order`**:** {`ID`, `AccountID`, `OrderName`}

`OrderDetails`**:** {`ID`, `OrderID`, `Productcode`, `ProductTitle`, ...}

**Now** I want to get the total count of orders which has associated 'Orderdetails' for a given account.

**More Info..**

Join these two tables on `OrderID` for a particular `AccountId` and get total count.

also remove duplicates.
that means order id repeats in the second table for product codes.

There are instances order is inserted without order details.That means `OrderID` not present in `OrderDetails`.

**My query'**

```
select count(*) from(
    SELECT MO.id
    FROM dbo.Order MO
    JOIN
        dbo.OrderDetails MOD ON 
        MO.ID = MOD.OrderID
        WHERE MO.AccountID ='123rt65-eee-ddd-ddd-dddddd'
        group by MO.ID) n
```

this gives me the correct count.

Is this the right way? or is there any better way to achieve this?

Thanks

SNA

Comment: you can use distinct so that it will avoid duplicate entry counts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this without subquery:

```
select count(distinct MO.ID)
from dbo.Order as MO
    inner join dbo.OrderDetails as MOD on MOD.OrderID = MO.ID
where MO.AccountID ='123rt65-eee-ddd-ddd-dddddd'
```

or, as you don't need data from `OrdersDetails`:

```
select count(*)
from dbo.Order as MO
where
    MO.AccountID ='123rt65-eee-ddd-ddd-dddddd' and
    exists (select * from dbo.OrderDetails as MOD where MOD.OrderID = MO.ID)
```

BTW, it's better to not call your table `Order`, because this is reserved keyword for `order by`.

Comment: thanks. The original table name is not order.this is a sample i created based on original

Comment: which one of this is a better query? and why?

Comment: Second one is better because it's not doing join and then count distinct id, instead it's just filter out all Order which don't have corresponding record in OrderDetails

Comment: what RDBMS are you using, BTW? SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL?

Comment: @SNA SQL is just a  Structured Query Language. is it SQL Server?